# How can I put another 3 buttons on this WXPython programs

Tags: python, button, wxpython

I'm new programming in WXPython and I Took this program from internet to start programming a visual program.

But How can I put 3 more buttons on this program without having errors?

```
import wx
class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        try:
            image_file = "roses.jpg"
            bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))
            def InitUI(self):    


                str1 = "%s  %dx%d" % (image_file, bmp1.GetWidth(), bmp1.GetHeight()) 
                parent.SetTitle(str1)
        except IOError:
            print "Image file %s not found" % imageFile
            raise SystemExit
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.bitmap1, id=-1, label='Snake', pos=(200, 300))

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "An image on a panel", size=(640, 480))
panel1 = Panel1(frame1, -1)
frame1.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sorry for the error of the tittle of the question. It is just one program.

Comment: what error do you have ? Always put full error message in question.

Comment: The thing is that i have no errors. I just want to add 3 more buttons but I do not kanow how to.

Comment: `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated. You should use `wx.App(False)`. As for adding more buttons, just create some more button instances and change the position so they aren't on top of each other (or use a sizer)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it doesn't work for me. It gives me error "Segmentation faul"

Using `self.bitmap1` as a Button's parent seems strange for me so I tried to use `self` (Panel1) as a parent and it works for me.

I made some other modifications - I added `self.` to some variables, I added `self.parent`. I moved `InitUI`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class Panel1(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

        self.parent = parent

        try:
            self.image_file = "roses.jpg"
            self.bmp1 = wx.Image(self.image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.bmp1, (0, 0))
        except IOError:
            print "Image file %s not found" % self.image_file
            raise SystemExit

        self.InitUI()

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Snake', pos=(200, 300))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Apple', pos=(100, 100))

    def InitUI(self):    
        str1 = "%s  %dx%d" % (self.image_file, self.bmp1.GetWidth(), self.bmp1.GetHeight()) 
        self.parent.SetTitle(str1)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "An image on a panel", size=(640, 480))
panel1 = Panel1(frame1, -1)
frame1.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```